# Vercel React.js Deployment: Cannot find module: 'firebase'. Make sure this package is installed

Tags: reactjs, firebase, vercel

I deployed a react app to Vercel that uses firebase. The build exits with status code 1.
I have installed firebase using: "npm install firebase" and it is running well on the local environment. What would be the possible error?

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.
./src/firebase.js
Cannot find module: 'firebase'. Make sure this package is installed.
You can install this package by running: npm install firebase.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! neozon@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the appname@0.1.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2022-01-11T18_49_38_751Z-debug.log
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the `firebase` package isn't installed on the server (unlike on your local environment), which most likely reads the dependencies from the `package.json`.

To add `firebase` to your `package.json` on your local system, run:

```
npm install firebase --save
```

Comment: I have done this multiple times and verified package.json as well. I have the package installed with version: firebase@9.6.2. Build succeeds in my local environment and fails in the production server of Vercel with the error above.